# Can I extract a library .a into a iOS project from .ipa?

Tags: ios, binaryfiles, ipa, .a

I have an app installed, I have the .ipa and I have this question: is possible extract a static library file added to this application?

This application contains a static library in format .a, images and the files. I know how to extract the images from the .ipa and I know that is possible get the functions with reverse engineering, but I don't know if is possible extract the library added, because I only see binary files and images then extract .ipa, but I don't see the .a files.

Comment: Curious - why do you wish to do this?

Comment: Well, I developed an iOS app, I sold it and then other people change this to add functionality. Now, I haven't access to the new code and I would like test and experiment the changes with the modified library and my old code

Answer (score 0):

No. The app binary is all of your code and static libraries all combined (linked) into a single binary. There is no way to extract any specific library from the resulting binary.

Comment: Everything thing is combined inside a MachO file and its possible to extract .a files using **otool**

Comment: @Karim Are you trying to say that if an app is built from a bunch of code and, for example, 3 .a static libraries, that `otool` will let you recreate the 3 original .a files from the app binary? I find that unlikely.

Comment: yes you can since .a are pre compiled files so when you build your project they will be included with your binary you can even see it with apps like MachOView

Comment: @Karim Then you should post your own answer explaining how this is done.