# react native build ios framework

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I ejected the app made with expo to react native.
Android extracted with aar.
How can I extract ios into framework for use as a library?
I want to know how to extract a project made with react native to ios framework. Do you have a guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your react project in iOS view `react-native run-ios`. In your MacOS you can see a file for xcode under your ios folder for more please follow [Guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-run-a-react-native-app-on-ios-fc427be3c375/)

Comment: The question is wrong. 
Android extracted with aar. 
How can I extract ios into framework for use as a library?

Comment: Possibly you can't, depending to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643366/can-i-extract-a-library-a-into-a-ios-project-from-ipa). However you can try this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921725/adding-swift-framework-extracted-from-ipa)

Comment: @sjm Please use translate and not your english, I cannot understand what you need.

Comment: @DanielLogvin  I'd like to know if I can build with ios framework with react-native. 
I used a translator

Comment: I still cannot understand what are you asking for. Do you know how does react-native work? Do you know why is it for? Do you know which type of framework is it?

Comment: @sjm Basically what I said is if you look in to link 1 you cannot do this normally. However, in link 2 you could use some approach to decompile Xcode files as framework. If you are using another language and can't translate this, I cannot write more basic than this. If you just wanna start in iPhone you need Xcode and macOS

Comment: @DanielLogvin In the react native project, android could be extracted as aar. The client company requested to extract ios into the frameworks, not ipa. I would like to know if there is a similar method in iOS.

Comment: @samuhay 
Thanks. I'll try the second link.